# Rancher failed to install (cattle-system CrashLoopBackOff) on OpenSUSE 15.4

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I am quite new in Kubernetes and installing Cluster with Rancher first time..
Errors:

```
kubectl -n cattle-system rollout status deploy/rancher
error: deployment "rancher" exceeded its progress deadline
```

```
kubectl -n cattle-system get events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON              OBJECT                                         MESSAGE
53m         Normal    Scheduled           pod/rancher-86df5b74c9-244xx                   Successfully assigned cattle-system/rancher-86df5b74c9-244xx to opensuse-rancher3
53m         Normal    Pulling             pod/rancher-86df5b74c9-244xx                   Pulling image "rancher/rancher:v2.7.1"
52m         Normal    Pulled              pod/rancher-86df5b74c9-244xx                   Successfully pulled image "rancher/rancher:v2.7.1" in 1m10.457999849s
49m         Normal    Created             pod/rancher-86df5b74c9-244xx                   Created container rancher
50m         Normal    Started             pod/rancher-86df5b74c9-244xx                   Started container rancher
32m         Warning   Unhealthy           pod/rancher-86df5b74c9-244xx                   Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.244.2.4:80/healthz": dial tcp 10.244.2.4:80: connect: connection refused
<cut>
53m         Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/rancher-86df5b74c9                  Error creating: pods "rancher-86df5b74c9-" is forbidden: no PriorityClass with name rancher-critical was found
53m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/rancher-86df5b74c9                  Created pod: rancher-86df5b74c9-244xx
53m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/rancher-86df5b74c9                  Created pod: rancher-86df5b74c9-b7lw9
53m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/rancher-86df5b74c9                  Created pod: rancher-86df5b74c9-xctzx
53m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/rancher                             Scaled up replica set rancher-86df5b74c9 to 3
3m10s       Warning   ErrGetKeyPair       issuer/rancher                                 Error getting keypair for CA issuer: secret "tls-rancher" not found
3m10s       Warning   ErrInitIssuer       issuer/rancher                                 Error initializing issuer: secret "tls-rancher" not found
53m         Normal    CreateCertificate   ingress/rancher                                Successfully created Certificate "tls-rancher-ingress"
53m         Normal    IssuerNotReady      certificaterequest/tls-rancher-ingress-xwkqd   Referenced issuer does not have a Ready status condition
53m         Normal    cert-manager.io     certificaterequest/tls-rancher-ingress-xwkqd   Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
53m         Normal    Issuing             certificate/tls-rancher-ingress                Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
53m         Normal    Generated           certificate/tls-rancher-ingress                Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "tls-rancher-ingress-nv74k"
53m         Normal    Requested           certificate/tls-rancher-ingress                Created new CertificateRequest resource "tls-rancher-ingress-xwkqd"
```

```
kubectl logs rancher-86df5b74c9-244xx -n cattle-system
2023/03/30 10:38:49 [INFO] Rancher version v2.7.1 (bb1c35fc4) is starting
2023/03/30 10:38:49 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains:[] AddLocal:true Embedded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:false Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit.log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Features: ClusterRegistry:}
2023/03/30 10:38:49 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2023/03/30 10:38:49 [INFO] Running in clustered mode with ID 10.244.2.4, monitoring endpoint cattle-system/rancher
2023/03/30 10:38:50 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
<cut>
2023/03/30 10:38:56 [INFO] Applying CRD machinesets.cluster.x-k8s.io
2023/03/30 10:39:08 [FATAL] error running the jail command: exit status 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. What could be wrong?

Comment: you are installing rancher on a new k8s cluster, the first thing that you need to try to solv it's this "secret "tls-rancher" not found"

Comment: Hey, do I need to generate self-signed certyficate first using cert-manager pod? Its not clear to me.. ;) Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @c4f4t0r I was trying to generate a private key and certificate using cert-manager and Let's Encript too.. I found on cert-manager pod following error: `cert-manager/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="wrong status code '404', expected '200'"`

Comment: @c4f4t0r Sorted, Now I am trying to install Rancher with Private CA Signed Certificate, pods are crashing with error: `kubectl logs rancher-5f7bbc4967-8dvm5 -n cattle-system
<cut>
2023/04/03 06:06:38 [DEBUG] Catalog-cache running cleanup
2023/04/03 06:06:44 [DEBUG] CreateJail: called for [driver-jail]
2023/04/03 06:06:44 [DEBUG] CreateJail: jailPath is [/opt/jail/driver-jail]
2023/04/03 06:06:44 [DEBUG] CreateJail: Running script to create jail for [driver-jail]
2023/04/03 06:06:46 [FATAL] error running the jail command: exit status 2` Can you help please?

Comment: It could be this script is failing https://fossies.org/linux/rancher/package/jailer.sh